# Working on one git project from two computers - how to avoid intermediate commits?

Tags: git, dropbox, icloud-drive

There are several questions concerning working on one project from two computers (desktop at work, laptop at home), but I did not find onre which adresses the problem of intermediate (non functional) commits, i.e. "eveneing" commits.

I have am the only developer of some github projects, and would like to work from two computers, and not having to commit half-ready commits.

I am wondering:

Can I put the project directory (the git repo) on iCloud / Dropbox, and just continue exactly where I left off on the one computer before on the other computer?

The advantage would be, that the folder would be exactly the same, including files not in iCloud / Dropbox.

Any downsides / risks to this approach?

Comment: Commits should be 'atomics', in theory. I'm in the same case (one dev / multiple desktops), but I never have this problem since I commit my changes something like every 10 minutes...

Comment: You could also commit an unfinished work, then git pull and git reset?

Comment: You could also create temporary branch for intermediate commits and then squash merge.

Comment: This is against the nature of git. It is better to commit, even if it is wildly unfinished work. With proper commit messages, you can later squash and rebase your work, so that your git history is clean. That way you don't rely on a third-party service like Dropbox. Here are some downsides - you don't commit, then you don't have a message to remind you what you did. You don't commit, you can't go back to that point and try a new approach. You loose access to your Dropbox, you loose your work.

Comment: Thanks for all these comments. They make perfect sense. @RajniKewlani True - I like that idea. @mnestorov That is what I would like to do. But as the project lives on github (and is / will be public) I would rather not litter my history with to many temporal commits. @olinox14 I would rather not change h=the history on github (can I actually?) so I think I will lean towards a temporary branch system where I will delete the branch later. I just have to figure out the `squash merge` at the end.

Comment: You need to learn about "interactive rebase", which is the main way to modify the history ;)

Comment: Yeah - I have heard about it. I should look it up again. So the workflow, would be 1. Create temporary branch on which only I work 2. Commit whenever I want, even in between atomic commits. 3.use interactive rebase to clean up the temporary branch 4. merge it into the main branch (dev, feature branch, ...). Correct?

Comment: Exactly, the workflow you just described is what I do. I also like to have a second remote I call dev, where I push those temporary branches. In my case, that repo is private so my collaborators only see my final work, although it's also perfectly fine to push a branch called `dev.featureX` or `dev.working-on-bugY`. As long as your name is clear, other will understand the temporary intent of the branch.

Comment: Dropbox and Git hate each other. :-) More seriously, if you put your Git repository into some sort of automated file updater (dropbox and other "cloud shared" systems), the sharer tends to corrupt the Git repository because it thinks Git is a flexible human who can deal with his files being renamed or "adjusted" in various ways, and that's just not true. So that's not a good idea.